# React Native Remote Notifications

Tags: react-native, push-notification

So what are your experiences with sending remote notifications to RN app from FCM?

I did some research today, tried bunch of tutorials, but most of them didn't work.

So I wanna hear your opinion, which library are you using for this and what guide did you follow?

- react-native-push-notification
- react-native-fcm
- react-native-firebase
- react-native-onesignal

Answer (score 1):

I did the connection a few days ago. It is not difficult but it requires a lot of configuration as notification is a native feature. I recommend you the following library that can help you:

[React Native FCM](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm)

Also take in count the following things:

- For ios you need get some [certificates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs) from apple.
- This [guide](https://blog.botreetechnologies.com/how-to-send-push-notification-to-the-android-phones-using-react-native-and-fcm-b28e1746da7b) help with the setup and android part.
- Remote notification can't reach iOS emulator since it can't fetch APNS token. Use real device.

Answer (score 0):

I used to react-native-fcm, but now I use react-native-firebase, it is simple to use, just follow the documentation https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/getting-started
just follow the installation tab guide, cloud messaging tab guide, and notification tab, also you can find js code there. for IOS part, you need some extra work to add some certificate to your developer id and add some certificate to your firebase app.

Comment: In react native there is no configuration for android or IOS. So, there is no mainfist file for android for example. In all tutorials for **react native** they tend to use configurations found only in native apps (android studio for example)